# Div para loading ajax em tela cheia?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Estou usando o Bootstrap 3 e criei uma `<div>` que funciona em tela cheia para um loading de ajax, isto funciona bem caso a tela esteja encaixada, sem barra de rolagem na vertical. Mas agora notei que se a página tiver barra de rolagem na vertical, ou seja, seja uma página com o `heigth` maior que o definido a `<div>` de loading não é exibida na tela toda, ela não se auto ajusta.

Como resolver esse problema ?

**CSS**

```
/** loading */
#div_loading  {    
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:11;
    background-color:#000;
    min-height:100%;
    width:100%;    
    height:auto;
    opacity: .50;
    filter: alpha(opacity=65);
    background-image: url(../Imagens/ajaxloader.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 60px;
    display:none;    
}
```

Aqui uma imagem de como fica quando tem rolagem na vertical.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Já tentou com `position: fixed`?

```js
$(".overlay").mouseover(function(){
    $(".overlay").css("background-image",
    "url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8t6P3.gif)",
    );
});

$( ".overlay" ).click(function() {
    alert( "Click!" );
});

$(".overlay").mouseout(function(){
    $(".overlay").css("background-image",
    "url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNGOI.gif)",
    );
});
```

```css
.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: rgba(70,20,15,0.3);
    z-index: 2;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNGOI.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 100px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" class="overlay"></div>
<h1>Иус ат веро афферт</h1>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tincidunt sollicitudin facilisis. Ut tempor odio non iaculis cursus. Cras fermentum porttitor dui, vel consectetur risus auctor id. Integer a congue erat. Vivamus vulputate ex lacus, vel vehicula neque varius non. Ut eu turpis luctus, placerat ante nec, pharetra metus. Aenean turpis diam, consectetur eu odio vitae, hendrerit pharetra mauris. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Phasellus accumsan tempor cursus. Phasellus dictum lacinia metus, eu dignissim leo lacinia et. Vivamus hendrerit imperdiet dictum. 
In sem eros, vestibulum feugiat efficitur ut, scelerisque ac diam. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec ullamcorper sem nisi, at rutrum orci viverra vel. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse sollicitudin lobortis nunc, non pretium erat tempor vitae. Mauris porta malesuada lorem eu elementum. Nulla libero elit, feugiat a ullamcorper sed, pulvinar ac augue. Cras lacinia mauris vel mauris faucibus consequat. Morbi est mauris, semper eget ante ut, euismod ornare mi. Ut ligula erat, tincidunt eu erat ac, ultricies finibus turpis. 
</p>
<ul>
<li>Donec scelerisque dui leo, a luctus mi luctus sed</li>
<li>Aenean tempus dui libero, at aliquet odio</li>
<li>Vestibulum imperdiet bibendum metus</li>
<li>Pellentesque ut rutrum augue</li>
<li>Magna fermentum orci pretium</li>
<li>Maecenas mi mi, convallis rutrum ultrices ac</li>
<li>Proin at lectus massa</li>
<li>Fusce vehicula arcu odio</li>
<li>dapibus lorem</li>
</ul>
<p>
ლორემ იფსუმ დოლორ სით ამეთ, ცუ ეოს რიდენს ფუთანთ ინიმიცუს, აეთერნო დისცერე ნამ ეი. ესთ მოდო მალორუმ დენიყუე ათ, ნისლ ყუოთ იდ მეა, ნამ ნო აუგუე მელიუს. ნეც ნო მოდუს მინიმ დოცენდი, თე ფრი ადმოდუმ ცონსეცთეთუერ. გრაეცის ფერსეყუერის ეა ველ, ფოსსით სემფერ სეა ეუ. ეთ სით ევერთი დოლორეს, იუს ცუ ოდიო რიდენს ალიენუმ.
</p>
```